# Added command to path won't execute

Tags: linux, bash, shell, linux-mint

Okay so i tried to install NBFC.
I added the command to the $PATH permanently.
But if i say nbfc the shell doesn't know it.
I use the bash shell.
I added in the .bashrc file following

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/nbfc/
```

According to that official Installation page of NBFC its correct.
Check it here: https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/wiki/First-steps

The files in the /opt/nbfc/ directory are following:

> clipr.dll               NLog.dll 
>   Configs                 Plugins 
>   ec-probe.exe            StagWare.BiosInfo.dll 
>   nbfc.exe                StagWare.FanControl.Configurations.dll 
>   nbfc.exe.config         StagWare.FanControl.dll 
>   NbfcService.exe         StagWare.FanControl.Service.dll 
>   NbfcService.exe.config  StagWare.Settings.dll 
>   nbfcservice.sh          System.IO.Abstractions.dll

Im new to Linux. Hope you can help out.

Okay it works but i have to call it with:

```
mono /opt/nbfc/nbfc.exe
```

Comment: Did you restart the shell? Did you try `hash -r`?

Comment: Did you go out and back in again? Also, is mini installed?

Comment: @DavidPostill yup its definitly in the $PATH variable

Comment: @davidgo what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry to ask a dumb question, but did you by chance install a Windows package instead of one for Linux?  The .DLL and .EXE files made me wonder.  At any rate, it looks like the executable's name is "nbfc.exe" not merely "nbfc".  What happens if you try to invoke the name "nbfc.exe"?

Comment: @JimL. well i downloaded the linux file since it was a .tar.gz file. and i just realized that it works if i call it per mono <directory>.